# Bind an AppWidget to a Service

Tags: android, android-widget

I implemented a service and I bind my activities in the app to it.. How can I bind an AppWidget too? I need to call some service's method from AppWidget's buttons...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot bind an app widget to a service directly. You need to implement a broadcast receiver and broadcast messages back and forth. If that doesn't work for you (maybe broadcasts take too long) then create a utility class to handle the work and call that from within your app widget

Comment: It's strange, brodcast receiver seems not to work for me.. I can't find any example on the internet... can you provide one please?? thank you!

Comment: You would broadcast an intent from the activity/service and receive it in the onReceive() in the AppWidgetProvider. For what you are trying to do I would instead create a controller or utility class that acts as the middle-man between your AppWidget and your service.

Comment: Thanks done with a service :)

Comment: @Erenwoid it would be useful if you answer your own question telling us how you solved it